# How to mirror this linear gradient across the x-axis and adjust it upon zooming

Tags: css, d3.js

I have been working on an area chart for time series hovering closely over and under zero. I need zoom and focus/tooltip capabilities, which I have already implemented. You can drag-select an area of the chart, and it'll zoom in. Double-clicking zooms out.

I want to add emphasis to values furthest from zero using a light blue to dark blue linear gradient. I managed to add it for values above zero (0 to yMax).

How could I symetrically "mirror" this gradient effect for negative values ? The gradient should be semantically logical, e.g. the yMin depicted here at -0.5 should have about the color level of +0.5, not of yMax.

How could I apply the gradient to the line stroke as well ?

How to avoid the gradient distorting upon zooming ?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-deviation-chart-gradient
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this to work I changed two things. First is to make the gradient span the whole area "below" the chart line. It spans between lowest and highest values of `y`.

```
.attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")    
.attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", y(d3.min(data, (d) => d[1])))
.attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", y(d3.max(data, (d) => d[1])))
```

The next thing to do is to modify stops for the gradient. It is one gradient spanning from lowest `y` value to highest `y` value. The stops set in such a way that:

1. the "minimum color" is on the x axis,
2. the absolutely highest value of y gets the "maximum color"
3. the maximum value on the other side of x axis than 2. gets proportional color

Therefore I'm setting stops in another method

```
.selectAll("stop")                      
.data(this.getGradientData())
```

... and the method is written as such

```
getGradientData(): Array<T> {
const dataMaxValue = Math.max(...this.data.map(element => element[1]));
const dataMinValue = Math.min(...this.data.map(element => element[1]));
const valuesSpan = dataMaxValue - dataMinValue;  

if (Math.abs(dataMaxValue) > Math.abs(dataMinValue)) {
  const shorterPartToLongerPartRatio = Math.abs(dataMinValue) / Math.abs(dataMaxValue);
  const shorterPartToWholeRatio = Math.abs(dataMinValue) / valuesSpan;

  return [
    {offset: "0%", color: `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${shorterPartToLongerPartRatio})`},
    {offset: `${shorterPartToWholeRatio * 100}%`, color: 'lightblue'},
    {offset: "100%", color: "black"}
  ];
}

const shorterPartToLongerPartRatio = Math.abs(dataMaxValue) / Math.abs(dataMinValue);
const shorterPartToWholeRatio = Math.abs(dataMaxValue) / valuesSpan;
return [
  {offset: "0%", color: 'black'},
    {offset: `${100 - (shorterPartToWholeRatio * 100)}%`, color: 'lightblue'},
    {offset: "100%", color: `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${shorterPartToLongerPartRatio})`}
];
```

}

Please notice how I changed `darkblue` to `black`. This is an easy way to find a proportionate color value (with opacity) when the background is white. That can be improved with calculating a desired color.

The solution should work even when the negative values are greater than the positive values. Here is the modified example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-deviation-chart-gradient-zrghr2

@Edit: As for the question about avoiding gradient distortion upon zooming. Unfortunately you cannot prevent that. It's a problem old as computer graphics and the reason is there is just not enough colors available :)

@Edit2: The approach to look for the intermediate color is rather simple:

```
getIntermediateColor(colorOneRGB, colorTwoRGB, ratio) {
    const newR = colorOneRGB[0] + (colorTwoRGB[0] - colorOneRGB[0]) * ratio;
    const newG = colorOneRGB[1] + (colorTwoRGB[1] - colorOneRGB[1]) * ratio;
    const newB = colorOneRGB[2] + (colorTwoRGB[2] - colorOneRGB[2]) * ratio;
    return `rgb(${newR}, ${newG}, ${newB})`;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I like your ratio idea, it's clever. However, I really need a blue to blue gradient to match a specific branding, so while I understand the gradient to/from black makes `{offset: "100%", color: `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${shorterPartToLongerPartRatio})`}` practical to compute, I can't rely on black shades. How would you go replacing that line ?

Comment: And how would you go about painting the line display as well ? Without a line stroke, the areas appear disconnected and odd.

Comment: As to the distorsion, I guess I should have been clearer. I'd the colors to not move upon zooming, e.g. in real life, zooming an object doesn't see its color changing/migration. I suppose this would require (x0/y0) and (x1/y1) for the gradient element to be recomputed in the zoom function.

Comment: About the colours I'd use a method to search for the intermediate colour using the same ratio as with the rgba. I edited in the `getIntermediateColor()`.

The line looks good to me. Imagine it was the same color as the values - you might as well not draw the line at all and leave just the gradient.

And the zooming. That would need a recalculation on zoom. I think it may be a little difficult to get the zoomed area coordinates to get where to compute the zoom into. But it's doable in a similar manner if you generalise the `getGradientData` a little.

Comment: Oh, and I updated the stackblitz, you can take a look

Comment: I found a way to make the gradient static; upon zoom, I move out the x,y coordinates of the gradient inversely proportionally to the zoom the size, with the same transition speed as the rest. The effect is that it feels like the gradient is not moving upon zoom.

Comment: The last bit I am wondering about is how to paint the line stroke. Full kudos if you have a working example of that one !

Comment: @BuZz moving the x y coordinates of the gradient is what I said in my answer ...

Comment: Also, add .myline {
  stroke-width: 0px;
} to styles.css to avoid displaying the line stroke

Comment: Thats smart with the zooming, cool that it works. WIth the stroke is something like @vals says. Also the `.attr("stroke", "transparent")` should get rid of the stroke effectively showing only the gradient

Answer (score 3):

For the first question, here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-deviation-chart-gradient-d3qp1t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdeviation-chart%2Fdeviation-chart.component.ts), also note for the gradient to work you have to multiply the `y1` by 2 along with gradient `offset`:

```
svg.append("linearGradient")                
    .attr("id", "area-gradient")            
    .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")    
    .attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", y(0) * 2)         
    .attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", y(yExtent[1]))        
  .selectAll("stop")                        
    .data([                             
      {offset: "0%", color: "darkblue"},
      {offset: "50%", color: "lightblue"},  
      {offset: "100%", color: "darkblue"},
    ])
```

Question 2, if you add gradient that would make it invisible and remove the whole purpose of having it there since it have the same color as the fill area.

Question 3, *"How to avoid the gradient distorting upon zooming ?"* I'm not facing issue with zooming, which browser are you using?

Comment: `.attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", y(0) * 2)` and  `.attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", y(yExtent[1])) ` fail to take changing data into account so that the whole color span gets drawn no matter the data array.

Comment: on Question 2, I disagree, the areas look very much disconnected without a line stroke on top

Comment: on Question 3, I misexplained: when zooming an sub-area, the colors of that sub-area should not change. Currently they do because the same gradient gets applied to smaller zone, hence changing the colors. e.g. zooming around the 0 on the y-axis should not start painting that zone in dark blue after the zoom.

Comment: Hmm, I understand your first comment, but for the second comment you mean the stroke  line "the blue line", right? and for the 3rd comment I got it now, will check if I can do it, also there one thing I would like to ask, is it ok to change the brush to zoom-pan instead? that would have made it easier for you to avoid the 3rd issue [zoom block](https://jarrettmeyer.com/2018/08/10/d3-zoom)

Comment: About the stroke line, correct. About the zoom, I really need it as is :(

Comment: I will have a look at it today, will get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

I am not proficient with d3, so I can not help you much with the code.

However, let me explain you a way to solve your problem

Calculate the min and max values of y in your data

This lines of code taken from wiktus239 response seem to do this

```
const dataMaxValue = Math.max(...this.data.map(element => element[1]));
const dataMinValue = Math.min(...this.data.map(element => element[1]));
```

Now take the biggest of the absolute values of those.

```
const dataLimit = Math.max (Math.abs(dataMaxValue), Math.abs(dataMinValue));
```

The gradient should be drawn between -dataLimit and +dataLimit.

Now, map this data  values to the graph y values. I believe this is done with the y function, but if I am wrong replace for the appropiate method

```
const yMax = y(dataLimit);
const yMin = y(-dataLimit);
```

This data is what you need to set on the gradient :

```
.attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")    
.attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", yMax)
.attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", yMin)
```

the offset remains the same

```
  {offset: "0%", color: "darkblue"},
  {offset: "50%", color: "lightblue"},  
  {offset: "100%", color: "darkblue"},
```

This solution should fix your questions 1 and 3.

About the second one, you could set stroke-width: 0, so the stroke of the  line will just not be visible